# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a problem in the next code:

```
  var a = g_table_board.DATA[6][c];
  var b = g_table_board.DATA[r+1][c];
```

r is 5 and c is 3,  g_table_board.DATA is 7x7 matrix

The first line works well, but the second one produce the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined
```

The question, is why r+1 produces this error if r+1 is 6?

Any idea?

Comment: Where do you declare `r`? Maybe it's a string and you concatenate 1 and it turns `51` (I know that the name of every property is converted into string, but I'm saying about concatenation)

Comment: One might be a number and the other a string?

Comment: If you don't want to show `r`, then log `r + 1` and show it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god!!!, it's true. r is a string and r+1 is "51" and not 6!!

thanks a lot for your help